# How can I randomly re-display a box containing information about products from my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

This is a Rails 3.0 project. I could build a partial that is set to refresh periodically and pull from a list of products, and I could use jQuery redisplay the partial. Is that the Rails  Way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [jQuery Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/), and it is super-simple to use and does the job great. I now have a rotating product showcase on the page.